# How to pass params via router in Next14?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How can I pass parameters via the router using NextJS 14?

I am creating an application where there are multiple items, when a user clicks an item, they should navigate to the item's standalone page. I want my url to be `http://localhost:3000/clicked-item-name` and not `http://localhost:3000/3` as in the item id.

Now the issue is that whenever this item is clicked, I want to navigate to a new page where another fetch request is performed using the clicked item id!

when I name my folder **[itemId]** and I pass the title, obviously as a param I get {itemId: "passed-title"} but how can I pass the id as additional param?

I've tried:

```
      onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: '/items/${title}',
          query: { id: item.id },
        })
      }}
```

but it seems like I can't use it in Next14 and I have to use 'next/navigation'.

Any suggestions on how can I keep my url as the item name and pass alongside it the id, without adding it to the url as `?id=${id}` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const url = format({
    pathname: '/items/${title}',
    query: { id: item.id },
 });

router?.push(url);
```

This is how I found a work around since router.push from useRouter only accepts a string in next.js 14.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a catch-all route. Catch all routes are defined with square brackets like `[...item]`. This will allow you to call the url `/id/my-item-name` without passing it as query parameter.

Inside your page you can then access it like in the example below:

```
interface Props {
  params: { item: string[] },
}

// route: app/items/[...item];
export default async function Page(props: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const [id, title] = props.params.item;
  return <p>You clicked item {id}, with title: {title}</p>;
}
```

Inside your components you can then add (n) path segments to the url. You either can use the router object or a link component:

```
// as a link
const ItemLink = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { id, title } = props;
  return <Link href={`/items/${id}/${title}`}>See item details</Link>;
};

// as a button
const ItemButton = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { id, title } = props;

  const router = useRouter();
  const onClick = () => router.push(`/items/${id}/${title}`);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>See item details</Link>;
};
```

You can finde out more about Next.js's [routing patterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing) inside the official documentation. I strongly recommend you take a look at it.

Comment: would this keep my url clean without adding any ids to it? I just want my url to be "http://localhost:3000/name-of-clicked-item" ?

Comment: @andorando It would definitely pass an id, the url would be `/id/name-of-clicked-item`. The only other option I'd see for you is to pass the id as cookie or as header.

Comment: Reverting to Next12 would solve my problem, right? Thanks for taking the time to answer btw

Comment: @andorando Next.js 12 has the same logic, so even there you only really could solve it with a cookie, header or by doing something like `/items/my-item-title-myid`.